# Best way to bind DataGrid to generic list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind a `DataGrid` to a generic list in WPF.

The following code results in blank rows for each row of data in my list (i.e. if i have 5 rows, it shows 5 rows, but doesn't shows any data in the cells):

```
List<DataRow>  DataBindingSource = GuestList.Where(row =>
  (row.Field<long>("FK_GROUP_ID") == Int64.Parse(cmbGroup.SelectedValue.ToString())) &&
  (row.Field<long>("FK_AGE_GROUP_ID") != (int)L_Age_Group.Child))
  .ToList();

gvwAddultDetails.ItemsSource = DataBindingSource;
```

If I convert my list of objects to a `DataTable`, it works (shows data).  For example:

```
List<DataRow> DataBindingSource = GuestList.Where(row =>
  (row.Field<long>("FK_GROUP_ID") == Int64.Parse(cmbGroup.SelectedValue.ToString())) &&
  (row.Field<long>("FK_AGE_GROUP_ID") != (int)L_Age_Group.Child))
  .ToList();

gvwAdultDetails.ItemsSource = DataBindingSource.CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
```

*But if I had a `List<DataRow>`, how would I convert it to `DataTable`?*

**What is the best practice for binding a `DataGrid` to a `List' in WPF?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to bind `DataGrid` to generic list in WPF:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
Grid.DataContext = DataBindingSource;
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid
  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
  Name="Grid" />
```

But it probably won't work with `DataRow`, because in WPF, *if you want to bind to something, it needs to be a property*.

**- OTHER THOUGHTS -**

Here's how you can convert a generic list to a `DataTable`:

- [Generic List to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable)

How to bind `DataGrid` to generic list in WPF:

- [Why isn't my WPF Datagrid showing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672923/why-isnt-my-wpf-datagrid-showing-data)

Especially (a great feature in WPF):

- [`ObservableCollection<>` WPF Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672923/why-isnt-my-wpf-datagrid-showing-data/4652749#4652749)