# Populating DataGrid in WPF with anonymous type collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datacontext, anonymous-types

I'm populating datagrid with collection of anonymous types (I'm setting `DataGrid's DataContext` property). And there are no errors. And nothing dsiplayed in datagrid. I've tried to make the same with defined object collection, but again nothing is displayed. Please could you instruct me what to do.

Thanks!

### EDIT 1

Ok. I tried to set ItemsSource property and it works. But I'm getting strange result..

[image]

### EDIT 2

I don't know how but after 3d launch it now's working properly?

```
private void ShowABCResultsButtonOnClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var anonArray = new List<NormalizedResult> 
    { 
        new NormalizedResult
        { 
            Key = 1,
            Title = "Колос", 
            Volume = 1322.01m,
            Weighted = 6.7840m,
            Result = 6.7840m,
            Group = "A"
        },
        new NormalizedResult
        { 
            Key = 2,
            Title = "Украинский Новый", 
            Volume = 1250.47m,
            Weighted = 6.4169m,
            Result = 13.2009m,
            Group = "A"
        },
        new NormalizedResult
        { 
            Key = 3,
            Title = "Ржано-Пшеничный", 
            Volume = 1202.1m,
            Weighted = 6.1687m,
            Result = 19.3695m,
            Group = "A"
        }
    };

    this.dataGrid2.ItemsSource = anonArray;
}
```

this is my code.

And again I've launched.. and it displayed properly only the third time?

---

---

Comment: Hi, maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672923/why-isnt-my-wpf-datagrid-showing-data) will help you.

Comment: I'm not even sure what that screenshot shows... were there four records that you put into the ItemsSource property?

Comment: @Tim: I was able to recreate his picture using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` and anonymous types. Likely a limitation of automagic column generation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely need to do two things. The first, [as @Tim suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193387/populating-datagrid-in-wpf-with-anonymous-type-collection/6193418#6193418), is assign the query to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property.

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = from a in x
                         select new { Prop1 = a.A, Prop2 = a.B, ... };
```

<strike>The second bit will be to enable automatic column generation on your `DataGrid`:</strike>

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

**Edit**: I've recreated your picture using automatic column generation and anonymous types with a vanilla LINQ query. So you <strike>will need to be</strike> could use explicit columns to use or switch to a real type.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property 1"
                            Binding="{Binding Prop1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property 2"
                            Binding="{Binding Prop2}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Edit 2**: You CAN use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` just not with the bare `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is an anonymous type. By adding `ToList` the problem goes away.

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = (from m in typeof(int).GetMethods()
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = m.Name,
                              ReturnType = m.ReturnType.FullName
                          }).ToList();
```

XAML then goes back to:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Comment: What does stand for `Prop1`. Should I assign exact property name. And if it is what should I assign using anonymous objects?

Comment: Ok I understood about properties.. I'll try.

Comment: @helicera: I've changed my code slightly such that an anonymous type could be used without having to explicitly declare your columns. See my 2nd edit.

Comment: Could you please explain what the linq query does? Does it get properties i.e. PropName + PropRetType?

Comment: @helicera: Woops, it is merely a sample query, it is not magical at all. Replace everything with your own query but add `.ToList()` to the end!

Comment: Yes, you're right! I tried the first approach you've adviced and it works fine for me. Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure you should be setting the DataGrid's [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

please make sure you use the same properties name of your anonymous object when binding it in data Grid and make sure the collection contains items.