# Output data from loop to xaml scrollable table

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a loop like so:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Dictionary)
{
   listFirstColumn.Add(kvp.Key);    
   listSecondColumn.Add(kvp.Value);    
}
```

My question is how do I display data in WPF UI Framework, so that the listFirstColumn goes inside first column and listSecondColumn goes inside second.

All of which is scrollable.

What xaml tool do I use, list, grid? Also How do you output that data?
I can't seem to find a straightforward resource or answer

Comment: "*I can't seem to find a straightforward resource or answer*" - then you need to read some introduction into WPF, e.g. a book like *WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan. Here you would typically assign the `Dictionary` collection to the ItemsSource property of a ListView.

Comment: @Clemens isn't there an online resource or similar? I don't want a whole book for such a simple problem. I bet the solution is pretty easy

Comment: @Orangutan WPF `GridView` certainly will do what you want

Comment: @Andriy Shevchenko I was looking at [GridView Overview][1] However I cant find instructions how to output code to it


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/gridview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your view model where  `listFirstColumn` and   `listSecondColumn`  reside

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
public class Columns 
{
     public string Col1 { get; set; }
     public int Col2 { get; set; }
}
public IEnumerable<Columns> GridItems => listFirstColumn.Zip(listSecondColumn, (first, second) =>
    new Columns() { Col1 = first, Col2 = second })
```

If you don't want to declare a new class, check out this post: [Populating DataGrid in WPF with anonymous type collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193387/populating-datagrid-in-wpf-with-anonymous-type-collection)

I assume you used a code sample from `GridView` docs:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Col1}" Header="Whatever" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Col2}" Header="Whatever" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere, however I  really need to output lists (listFirstColumn.Add(kvp.Key) as they have some logic behind it and are sorted etc..

Comment: @Orangutan, do you need to change your lists in runtime or they are read-only?

Comment: @Oranguran if above is true, we can workaround this via a wrapper property which would zip two lists together and raise `PropertyChanged` in sync with lists.

Comment: Read only, I run a loop, put them in list and want to display them

Comment: @Orangutan updated my answer